# Erro ao tentar criar tabela no mysql – Multiple primary key defined

Tags: mysql

Estou criando um banco de dados e umas das tabelas não quer ser criada nem com reza.

Aparece o seguinte erro:

> Error Code: 1068. Multiple primary key defined

O que tem de errado em meu código?

```
CREATE TABLE `controle_ferramentas` (
  `requisitante_cpf` int NOT NULL primary key,
  `data_hora_emprestimo` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_hora_devolucao` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `area_producao_cultivo_id` int NOT NULL primary key,
  `almoxarifado_id` int NOT NULL primary key,
  FOREIGN KEY (`area_producao_cultivo_id`) REFERENCES `area_producao_cultivo` (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`almoxarifado_id`) REFERENCES `almoxarifado` (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`requisitante_cpf`) REFERENCES `funcionarios` (`cpf`)
);
```

Comment: Caso você queira definir uma chave primária composta então não coloque o atributo PRIMARY KEY em cada uma das colunas mas sim coloque numa cláusula PRIMARY KEY separada: `PRIMARY KEY (requisitante_cpf, area_producao_cultivo_id, almoxarifado_id)`. Você tem é que verificar se realmente faz sentido para seu modelo.

Answer (score 3):

Seu código contém:

```
area_producao_cultivo_id int NOT NULL (primary key), 
almoxarifado_id int NOT NULL (primary key)
```

Se o erro diz "multiple primary key defined", acredito que só pode ter uma "primary key" - "chave primária".

Tente deixar só uma primaria, geralmente eu deixo só o "id" no começo como primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro está dando ''Multiiple primary key'' porque por tabela só pode haver uma chave primária, se tem o cpf do requisitante então este vai ser uma chave primária e para os outros campos que você quer transformar em chave primária, por questão de organização, seriam de outras tabelas, e para selecionar tudo você utiliza o select e o where. Por definição só pode haver uma chave primária por tabela.

Você pode ter várias constraints unique mas primary key apenas uma por tabela.

Espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: entendido, vou manter somente uma chave primária, me desculpe o nivel da pergunta, é que estou iniciando na área. valeu!

Comment: Nem se preocupe com isso, sou iniciante tbm :)

Answer (score -2):

Na verdade, como citado acima, existe o conceito de chave composta funciona colocando o atributo PRIMARY KEY separado.

Para que o código acima funcione, será necessário colocar desta forma:

```
CREATE TABLE `controle_ferramentas` (
  `requisitante_cpf` int NOT NULL,
  `data_hora_emprestimo` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_hora_devolucao` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `area_producao_cultivo_id` int NOT NULL,
  `almoxarifado_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (requisitante_cpf, area_producao_cultivo_id, almoxarifado_id),  
  FOREIGN KEY (`area_producao_cultivo_id`) REFERENCES `area_producao_cultivo` (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`almoxarifado_id`) REFERENCES `almoxarifado` (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`requisitante_cpf`) REFERENCES `funcionarios` (`cpf`)
);
```